# How to automate the download of latest jdk file using shell scripting from oracle

Tags: shell, scripting

How to automate the download of latest jdk.exe file using shell scripting from oracle and convert to .zip file ?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk18-windows

You can directly download the .zip format from the oracle website.

There is no need to convert it from .exe to .zip.

Also, it would be better if you could clarify what shell you need. Considering that youre looking for .exe, im guessing powershell? But who knows...

Im guessing you would just need to copy the download link and have the script grab it from there. For example with bash it would be like below:

> #!/bin/bash
> curl https://download.oracle.com/java/18/latest/jdk-18_windows-x64_bin.zip -o latest_jdk.zip

[download zip file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gTMS.png)

Comment: By downloading directly gzip file , some folder under it like .rsrc are missing as I have downloaded and checked whereas .exe file consists of it .

Comment: in that case you would do the same but just replace the link.
```#!/bin/bash
curl  
https://download.oracle.com/java/18/latest/jdk-18_windows-x64_bin.exe -o latest_jdk.zip
zip -r latest_jdk.zip directory_name```
I would personally use tar or gz for compression but since you want to .zip it i used the `zip` command. you will probably need to install `zip` beforehand.